# Python 2.5.2 and Solaris 8 (gcc 3.4.2) build issues

Tags: python, gcc, build-process, solaris, environment-variables

I'm trying to build python 2.5.2 on Solaris 8 using gcc 3.4.2.  I can't see any immediate errors in the ./configure step but, once built and i enter the python shell doing an import time errors with :

```
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Nov 21 2008, 18:45:42)
[GCC 3.4.2] on sunos5
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import time
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named time
```

What am i doing wrong?  From what i can see with a cursory google is that there might be an error with libstdc++.so, but i can't find any hard details.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Many thanks,

Al.

Comment: Where is Python installed?  What is the PYTHONPATH?  What is sys.path currently set to?

Comment: Hi, 
For just now i have it in a local directory.  PYTHONPATH isn't set, sys.path is :
/usr/local/lib/python25.zip', '~/src/Python-2.5.2/Lib', '~/src/Python-2.5.2/Lib/plat-sunos5', '~/src/Python-2.5.2/Lib/lib-tk', '~/src/Python-2.5.2/Modules', '~/src/Python-2.5.2/build/lib.solaris-2.8-sun4u-2.5

Comment: I shortened the paths slightly in the last comment to fit.

Comment: @AlMcLean Can you please tell me how you got python-2.5 compiled on solaris 8? I'm trying to compile it for two days now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time module is not built by default in Python, if you build from a source distribution you need to explicitly enable all the modules you want to compile.

Open up Modules/Setup.dist in the python source tree and comment out the line which says:

```
#time timemodule.c
```

To enable the build of time module. Also remember that you need to recompile Python for this to take an effect.