# ActivePython 2.7.2 - how to install time as a builtin package?

Tags: python, activepython, built-in

I have installed [ActivePython 2.7.2](http://downloads.activestate.com/ActivePython/releases/2.7.2.5/ActivePython-2.7.2.5-linux-x86_64.tar.gz) in my linux machine. I need `time` to be builtin module instead of being loaded from `lib-dynload/time.so`

On searching Stackoverflow archives I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314749/python-2-5-2-and-solaris-8-gcc-3-4-2-build-issues) that you can do this by uncommenting

```
time timemodule.c
```

in `Modules/Setup.dist` in python [source](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tgz) tree

Can someone point out how to do this in ActivePython?